moving towards fewer tags
I heard that having tags with few posts associated with them is discouraged in StackExchange and I've scanned the LEGO Answers tags enough to spot a few anomalies:

adult-lego and afol are quite similar and only have 9 questions between them.  Should they be merged?
identification's definition includes "Trying to identify a LEGO element or set that you possess or have seen somewhere?" yet we also have part-identification with relatively few questions which seems to be a distinct subset of identification and many of the questions carry both tags.
model-identification could also be a subset of identification and most of those questions already carry both tags
can someone help me decide when something belongs in building vs design?
aren't investment and trading too similar?
couldn't abs get merged into plastics?  One question is already in both.
brands only has two questions: 1 is already in clone-brands and 2 doesn't benefit much from the tag.

Should we be cleaning this sort of thing up at this stage in the Beta process?

What is wrong with it?

Thanks for bringing these to attention, I've made changes to the most obvious ones:
The adult-lego tag is now a synonym of afol.
The tag abs has been removed.
The brands tag has been removed and replaced with clone-brands where applicable.
Remember tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period, occasionally a few tags get used on one or more questions when they perhaps should not be. 

The investment and trading tags are indeed very similar but there are quite a few trading questions that I would not consider appropriate to be classed using the investment tag. 
sets + identification seems to be used interchangeably with model-identification, I have removed the latter. 
I agree, identification, building and design tag could definitely be made clearer. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

That's awesome.  Thanks so much.
